# Detox Testing: Tracking down Javascript timers causing test framework to wait forever

Tags: javascript, testing, detox

The Detox test framework, according to the documentation [TroubleShooting Synchronization](https://github.com/wix/detox/blob/master/docs/Troubleshooting.Synchronization.md) mentions that the test framework will wait and only perform your next test statement when the app is "Idle".

The problem I have right now is that my app never goes idle because there's some timeout that's continuously firing. It could be in my code or third-party code.

Here's an example of the output:

[image: Detox info log]

As you can see something is creating a new timer every few milliseconds. What'd I'd like to do is track down which one, I can see the ids but don't know a good way to try and track down exactly where this (setTimeout) id is coming from.

- I thought of wrapping the setTimeout function, but not sure what's the best way to proceed with that.
- I could eliminate or at least wrap `setTimout` in my own code, that way, at least determining it's a third-party lib (which still doesn't help solve the problem).

Comment: Not an answer but helped me towards a solution. Inside `./node_modules/detox/src/client/actions/actions.js` there is a class called `CurrentStatus` where the following line was commented out: `//console.log("res:" + JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));` inside the `handle` method. It gives much more robust information about where the timers are being set. Hope that helps. `Detox 11.0.1`

Answer (score 0):

You could track down setTimeouts easily with:

```
 // DEV mode only!
 function failOnTimeout(func) {
   const setTimeout = f => {
     throw new Error(`Executing timeout \n ${f.toString()} \n`);
   };

   // A small trick to change scope:
   eval("(" + func.toString() + ")()");
}
```

So you can do:

```
 failOnTimeout(someMysteriousFunction);
```

And will give you stack traces of the first timeout set in that function (synchronously). You can then comment that out and search for the next one.

---

But instead of trackig down all timeouts, a quick solution could be to just throw an uncatched error to end the process.